# How to Unhook div from parent then hook it back?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='child'></div>
</div>
```

I'd like to unhook the child from the parent. Then do a bunch of different dom manipulations to the child, then hook it back to the parent-- so that the browser just does one reflow (as opposed to reflowing every time I change something in the child). How can I do this?

```
var child = document.getElementById('child');
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');

child.parent = null; // something like this
//.... // do a bunch of edits to the child then
child.parent = parent; // to set it back
```

Comment: Based on what I think you want...you could use CSS and set the position to absolute or fixed, while it'll still be under the parent it will not have to be positioned within it.  If this is not what you want and you want to remove the child out all together, then use something like jquery clone.  Clone the element to somewhere else delete the original, then append it back to the parent once complete.

Comment: I'd create a copy `clone` of the `#child`, do whatever you need to do with it (the `clone`), then replace the current one with the `clone`

Comment: clone/copy is too slow.. can't I just change references

Comment: `parent.removeChild(child)` and `parent.appendChild(child)`?

Comment: Just use the concept of immutability.  Create a new 'child' remove the original and append the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the child node using Node.removeChild() method, it removes a child node from the DOM. Returns removed node. Syntax `var oldChild = node.removeChild(child);`

child is the child node to be removed from the DOM. 
node is the parent node of child. 
 
oldChild holds a reference to the removed child node. oldChild === child.
The removed child node still exists in memory, but is no longer part of the DOM.  You may reuse the removed node later in your code to append back to the parent node, via the oldChild object reference.

Removing a specified element without having to specify its parent node

```
 var node = document.getElementById("nested");
 if (node.parentNode) {
 node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
 }
```

Removing all children from an element

```
var element = document.getElementById("top");
 while (element.firstChild) {
 element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
 }
```

Then you can use the `Node.appendChild()` to append back the oldchild to parent node. Note : The `Node.appendChild()` method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the original node, make the changes you need, remove the original one and add the changed node.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
    var child = document.getElementById('child');
    
    var clone = child.cloneNode(true);
    clone.innerHTML = '<p><strong>Changes</strong></p>';
    
    child.remove();
    parent.appendChild(clone);
  });
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='child'>Original</div>
</div>
<button id='mybutton'>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do in a simplified way, using pure javascript,

```
// This line you have the div chil
var child = document.getElementById ("child");
// This line you catch who is his father
  var parent = child.parentNode;
// This line the parent removes the child
     parent.removeChild (child);
// A function that will return the child in 5/2
setTimeout (function () {
   parent.appendChild (child);
}, 5000);
```